# Get values from list of object

Tags: java, mysql

I have a contact class that has a persons name, email and phone number. I then have a addressbook class that has an id, name, and a list of contact. So I want to add the addressbook to mysql database. I just want to make sure I am doing this correctly by retrieving the persons name, email and phone number from the list of contact from the adressbook class.Here is my code so far:

AddressBook Class:

```
public class AddressBook{
    private int id;
    private String name; 
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Contact Class:

```
public class Contact
{
    private String firstName, lastName, email, phoneNum;
    // getters and setters
}
```

DB Class:

```
public boolean insert(AddressBook addressBook)
    {
        boolean success = false;
        int executedValue = 0;

        try
        {
            Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String query = "INSERT INTO addressbook (id, firstname, lastname, email, phonenum)"
                    + "VALUEs (?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setInt(1, addressBook.getId());

            List<Contact> contacts = addressBook.getContacts();

            for(Contact contact : contacts)
            {
                 stmt.setString(2, contact.getFirstName());
                 stmt.setString(3, contact.getLastName());
                 stmt.setString(4, contact.getEmail());
                 stmt.setString(5, contact.getPhoneNum());
            }

            executedValue = stmt.executeUpdate();
            success = executedValue > 0;   
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Comment: well, does it work or not?

Comment: The code looks fine, except that possibly you don't want to be manually setting the ID if that could treated as an auto increment column.  But this is a design decision, not really a Java problem.

Comment: ID should be auto-created.  Transactions should be committed and should be rolled back in exception. Sessions should be closed or  returned to pull in finally block.

Comment: You're not supplying a value for `id`?  If it's automatic key, you don't need to supply in your insert statement

Comment: Also return false in the exception block.

Comment: @PrabirGhosh why is a return false necessary?

Comment: It seems the boolean return value in the code indicate success. If it is otherwise then let me what it is.

Comment: @PrabirGhosh The value of success is set after the `executeUpdate` so if an Exception is thrown the value will still be false

Comment: You are correct

Comment: I have a setter that randomly generates an ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have two classes but only one table? Why does the `AddressBook` class have a name if the `addressbook` table doesn't?

In short, your database is wrong. In order to have a single Address Book, with many contacts, you need an `addressbook` table with a one-to-many association to a `contact` table.

Not getting into the entire discussion about auto-generated keys/identifiers, I'll assume that your `addressbook` has a valid `id` column as primary key, and that your `contact` doesn't have an id of its own, but is a sub-table of `addressbook`, e.g. with a primary key of `id, firstname, lastname` where the `id` is the address book id. It's bad design, but maybe you want it that way.

If so, your code could be:

```
// Insert AddressBook
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO addressbook (id, name) VALUES (?,?)"
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, addressBook.getId());
    stmt.setString(2, addressBook.getName());
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}

// Insert Contacts
String sql2 = "INSERT INTO contact" +
             " (id, firstname, lastname, email, phonenum)" +
             " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, addressBook.getId());
    for (Contact contact : addressBook.getContacts()) {
        stmt.setString(2, contact.getFirstName());
        stmt.setString(3, contact.getLastName());
        stmt.setString(4, contact.getEmail());
        stmt.setString(5, contact.getPhoneNum());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Notice how the `executeUpdate()` is *inside* the `for` loop.

For performance, it would be better to use batch inserts:

```
// Insert Contacts
String sql2 = "INSERT INTO contact" +
             " (id, firstname, lastname, email, phonenum)" +
             " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, addressBook.getId());
    for (Contact contact : addressBook.getContacts()) {
        stmt.setString(2, contact.getFirstName());
        stmt.setString(3, contact.getLastName());
        stmt.setString(4, contact.getEmail());
        stmt.setString(5, contact.getPhoneNum());
        stmt.addBatch();
    }
    stmt.executeBatch();
}
```

Insert statements can't really fail silently, i.e. by returning a 0 update count, so checking the update count is meaningless. They can of course fail for duplicate keys, value overflows, bad SQL, etc., but that all causes a `SQLException`.

Comment: thanks for your help I'm going to change the database design